# Can I execute an ASP Classic page from within PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am mostly a Windows person so I have limited knowledge of PHP sorry. I have Googled but cannot seem to fine resources to help with the following.

I have a PHP site and an ASP Classic site. The ASP site contains a lot of back-end code for transaction processing and data management.

There are Two parts to my cry for help ...

a)
What I would like to do is call (execute not include) various ASP pages during the user performing various tasks on the PHP site.

In ASP generally I would use something like this ;

```
<%
response.write("I am in File 1!<br>")
Server.Execute("file2.asp")   ' runs the code in file2.asp
response.write("I am back in File 1!")
%>
```

and would pass whatever info to the files2.asp  page for that code to do its thing.

Question - How would I do this but from within a PHP page, to run an the files2.asp  page.

b)
Lets say now files2.asp is passing data back, for example the FName and LName and PhoneNumber (numeric) retrieved from an MSSQL DB.

Question - how is that written in the PHP page in order now to make those fields available to the PHP code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `curl` or `file_get_contents()` or `file()` to run the asp page age get the conetnets

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: Thanks to you both that helped.